# Two players connected to the same game computer

Tags: multiplayer, gamepad

I would like to know whether there exist games running on one computer but collecting input from two players using each a mouse or joystick connected to the same computer?

If they exist, how does the game keeps separated the data from the two mice/joysticks?

Thanks in advance, Stefan

Comment: several fighting games allow you to connect 2 joysticks, if that's what you mean. Even more, how is this question related with programming? edit: maybe you want to program a game like that?

Comment: Every joystick sends status info to the PC. Under Windows one can connect 2 mice but the OS takes the info from the two mice and uses it for moving the same pointer. This I want to avoid. How is in a game the data from the 2 joysticks kept separate? Once you connect the joystick to a USB port, Plug-and-Play starts connecting to a driver. What happens after the system understands how to communicate with the joystick? The second one does the same, links to the same driver. Is there a second service started? How do you communicate in the game with the 2 joysticks?

Comment: ah its different. Pretty much is resumed that the system expects to have only one mouse connected, while it realizes that it could have 0 or more joysticks connected. It assign a different instance to each joystick, same way it does with when you connect 2 flash memory usb sticks. As far as I know, nothing prevents that it could be programmed the ability to have 2 independent mouse cursors except that it makes no sense to do so.

Comment: Thanks Chris-I! I just thought about games by chance. Before I asked my question about optical mice to be used as encoders for position detection. For my application I need 2. Both come with a USB connection what is nice and bad at the same time. Both mice are easy to be integrated because the normal mechanisms work (PnP). It is bad because the normal mechanism does not make distinction between mice. Are the normal OS and mechanisms also used for games or do you reprogrammed your own OS? Any experience with wrappers or modification of drivers? Stefan

Comment: I never said I had experience modifying the drivers ;) but check the links on my answer, maybe they could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this seems to be similar to what you want. Teamplayer3 allows multiple mouse pointers at the same time: http://www.dicolab.com/products/teamplayer/

That is on windows. On *nix, check this project: http://www.icculus.org/manymouse/